# How can I hide characters in Microsoft Word using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, hide

I would like to hide characters in Microsoft Word, more specifically hide the text between some characters.

For example, if I got this:

```
::00-58-96:: Hello there
::00-58-97:: This is a test
::00-58-98:: Nothing else
::00-58-99:: Good bye !
```

I would like to hide the text between the

```
::        ::
```

And the result would be

```
Hello there
This is a test
Nothing else
Good bye !
```

Another example would be

```
==this:example== Again this
==this:example== Is a
==this:example== Test
```

And the result would be

```
Again this
Is a
Test
```

I do not know if I exposed my problem well.

I've already tried to do this (some other people help me) but this replace the text, not hide it:

```
Sub l()
'
'
'
    ActiveDocument.Range.Select '

With Selection.Find
     .MatchWildcards = True
     .Text = "::*::"
     .Replacement.Text = ""
     .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
     Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With


End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

Word is still crashing/just hidden the first line of my document, I've modify just one line as follows :

```
Private Sub SelFind()


    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Fnd As Boolean

G:
    Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range


    With Rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute FindText:=";;*;;*;;", Forward:=True, _
                 Format:=False, Wrap:=wdFindStop
        Fnd = .Found
    End With

    If Fnd = True Then
        With Rng
            .MoveStart wdWord, 0
            .Select
            With .Font
                .Hidden = True
            End With
        End With
        GoTo G

    Else:

    MsgBox "All done"

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way you can Hide text in Word without VBA, manually from toolbar ?

Comment: There is one :  when you go to > Font then in the Effects section, box Hidden will do it, but when you got really big files, you loose huge amount of time doing this, that's the reason why I'm searching a Macro for this desperately.

Comment: Set `.Font.Hidden = True` for the found text.

Comment: @Satanas .. Use the Code in Answer now... Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
Private Sub SelFind()


    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Fnd As Boolean

G:
    Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range


    With Rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute FindText:="::*::", Forward:=True, _
                 Format:=False, Wrap:=wdFindStop
        Fnd = .Found
    End With

    If Fnd = True Then
        With Rng
            .MoveStart wdWord, 0
            .Select
            With .Font
                .Hidden = True
            End With
        End With
        GoTo G

    Else:

    MsgBox "All done"

    End If
End Sub
```

Took help from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43289801/5720144)

Comment: Woah thank you, this normally should work perfectly as you says but the only problem is that my Word crashes after the macro is executed, I will search the possibles problem but thanks i should be able to modify this code from now :)

Comment: Try running using F8 step by step, that ways you will know why it's crashing and after how many searches.

Comment: I see, the macro is applied to only the first line :) even if the GoTo is sending to the beginning of the macro to iterate again

Comment: That should not be the case...as I have tried and tested it.

Comment: `;;00:00:08;;00:00:10;;delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias
;;00:00:11;;00:00:13;;qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti
;;00:00:14;;00:00:15;;Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis
;;00:00:15;;00:00:17;;Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum
;;00:00:18;;00:00:20;;non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic
;;00:00:22;;00:00:23;;praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores` 
Can you please try with this ? Its the original text from my source.

Comment: Yes .. This file has the code ..[see](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NRsW1s1dmlFGKmrCG7mu8Qh3jD2uhSyX)