# Word VBA: Find a string of text and change all instances of it to title case

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write a macro to change the case of "section 1", "section 2", etc. to title case, so they all read "Section 1" etc. I've adapted [Variatus' very helpful code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284752/vba-word-i-would-like-to-find-a-phrase-select-the-words-before-it-and-italici/43289801) here:

```
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Fnd As Boolean

Set Rng = Selection.Range
With Rng.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Execute FindText:="section [0-9]", Forward:=True, _
             Format:=False, Wrap:=wdFindContinue, MatchWildcards:=True
    Fnd = .Found
End With

If Fnd = True Then
    Rng.Case = wdNextCase
End If
```

The issue I'm having with this is that it only changes one instance at a time. Ideally it would change the case of all instances with one keypress.

As a bonus, I'd also like it to register the change of case as a tracked change. As I'm using tracked changes, I can't do a simple replace text macro with `section ([0-9])` for `Section \1`, as the bug with tracked makes it "1Section ", "2Section ", etc. This isn't essential but would be a really nice bonus. The `.Case` function doesn't get tracked, and `.Font` only has an option for `.AllCaps`.

Perhaps there's a way it can find `section [0-9]`, move the cursor to the beginning of the word and select the first letter, set `.Font.AllCaps = True`, and loop until there are no more instances of `section [0-9]`? Just an idea, but that's way beyond my macro ability at the moment. The main thing for now is getting the above code to apply to all instances of `section [0-9]`.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "section [0-9]"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    .Characters.First.Text = "S"
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```